# Why doesn't Mathematica reduce ln(e) to 1 by default?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Given `D[eⁿ, n]`, Mathematica produces:

```
eⁿ Log[e]
```

Why? (Or rather, why not just `eⁿ`?)

Comment: Case sensitivity. In particular, `E != e`.

Comment: To add to that: note that when you type `e` in Mathematica it will be highlighted as blue, while `E` is black. Blue symbols don't have definitions (either user-defined or build-in), so the fact that `e` is blue is a hint that Mathematica considers it just to be a variable and nothing more.

Comment: If you want to use the more familiar notation for the exponent, it's easily entered as `esc`ee`esc`.  This is rendered as a math double stroke lowercase e, but behaves as as the exponential `E`.   `D[\[ExponentialE]^n, n]===\[ExponentialE]^n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Built-in symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NamesOfSymbolsAndMathematicalObjects.html) are capitalized.

You want `E` (or `esceeesc`), not `e`.

Comment: Quick and easy! Thank you! Added an edit to your comment to make it a little more useful to future visitors, I hope. (I feel like an idiot! )